# Do exchanges or brokers control bulk trade activities?

Tags: stock-analysis

The following is the chart for **AAPL** for 1/17/2020. There were two dips before **1:15 PM** and at 1:15 PM, the stock went up to close higher. I speculate that the reason behind the surge is the news that came out at 1:15 PM.

1. Do Analysts follow any patterns when they announce news (positive or negative)? For example, they would like to release a positive news when the stock is flat or down? Or negative news when the stock is going higher.
2. In this case of the news, how do we confirm that this news is not fake. If this is not fake, should not it have come from Apple company itself and not Morgan Stanley?
3. Do the exchange or brokers control what type of activity should be traded? For example, run all the BUYs and then SELLs so the graph follow a pattern?
4. There is a pattern in this graph. There are two dips before 1:15 PM, then after the news the stock went up. In a scenario like this, do the brokers control whether to execute BUYs or SELLs and what volume? For example, a positive news came out so all the large BUYs need to be executed right away.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a reasonable speculation that the reason behind the surge at 1:15 PM was news.  It's also possible that it was just due to institutional buying of AAPL or AAPL getting carried higher by the market at that time.  Any decent broker providing a streaming real time  news feed would show what, if anything occurred at 1:15 PM. You could check the other possibilities as well.

News from the company is released to the media and all news networks (Dow Jones, Bloomberg, etc.) then report it.  Broker specific news comes from the broker, eg. an analyst releasing an opinion about the company.

SEC rules regulate and prohibit "fake news".  Watch Sean Hannity if you want some of that :->).  Even if analysts and brokers were  to"release a positive news when the stock is flat or down? Or negative news when the stock is going higher", do you really think that a little retail guy is going to get in on that? And don't waste your time on pattern recognition as well as looking for bogeymen and conspiracies.